# Unexpected behavior of doctrine entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a helper service that links me to a database on the fly.

```
$databaseName = 'db_x'; 

$em = $this->entityManagerProvider->get($databaseName);
```

I can use this entity manager like this:

```
$car = new Car();
$car->setName('Audi');

$em->persist($car);
$em->flush();
```

It works good! Object was inserted to my db_x

But If I run repository method on this entity manager:

```
$em->getRepository('App\Entity\Car')->findById(1);
```

Then entity manager try run on my default database, not db_x. How it is possible?

My service to switch database:

```
namespace App\Utils\Database;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class EntityManagerProvider
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $databaseName
     * @return EntityManagerInterface
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     */
    public function get($databaseName): EntityManagerInterface
    {
        return EntityManager::create(
            $this->configureParams($databaseName),
            $this->entityManager->getConfiguration(),
            $this->entityManager->getEventManager()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $databaseName
     * @return array
     */
    private function configureParams(string $databaseName): array
    {
        $params = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->getParams();

        unset(
            $params['dbname'],
            $params['path'],
            $params['url'],
            $params["wrapperClass"]
        );

        $params['dbname'] = $databaseName;

        return $params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sure it is the exact same $em instance?  Does your repository extend from ServiceEntityRepository?

Comment: @Cerad, yes extend ServiceEntityRepository...

Comment: A ServiceEntityRepository find the first entity manager which supports your entity.  That seems to be what is happening though I would have thought that $em->getRepo would always use $em.  Just for kicks, try extending the repository from EntityRepository and see if that makes any difference.  Just a guess.

Comment: And while unrelated, using the same event manager for different entity managers might also cause some amusing problems.  Never tried it.  I would probably avoid making my EntityManagerProvider dependent on the default entity manager.  I see what you are trying to do.  Just not sure if it will actually work or not.

Comment: I should think about another solution, but extending from EntityRepository looks work! Thank you.